# Update Table Cell Data w/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, cell, updates

This is my table format.

```
<table id="table1">
 <tr id="row_1">
  <th>Some Heading</th>
  <td class="t1"></td>
  <td class="t2"></td>
  <td class="t3"></td>
  <td class="t4"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="row_2">
  <th>Some Heading</th>
  <td class="t1"></td>
  <td class="t2"></td>
  <td class="t3"></td>
  <td class="t4"></td>
 </tr>
 etc...
</table>
```

How do I update the content of the separate table cells (td) using jQuery? A better way to put it would be how do I write it if I want to update the content of #row_1 cell 1 or #row_2 cel 4, etc?

I have another table which I can update data in no problem, but it's also a lot simpler. It only has one table cell per row that needs content updated. I did it using this.

```
$('#val_' + i).html("stuff I put in it");
```

Each cell has a unique id - #val_ + some number identifying it so I can easily loop through it, but the slightly more complex table is giving me trouble.

Comment: `$( '#row_1 .t1' )` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#table1').children('tr').each(function() {

    // where 'x' is the index of the <td> to target
    var $requiredCell = $(this).children('td').eq(x);

    doStuff( $requiredCell );

});
```

Or if you're just targeting a single cell overall

```
$('#row_1 td.t1');
```

Or

```
$('#row_1 td').first(); // If you can't use the classes...
```

Or

```
$('#row_1 td').eq(x); // for targeting a td at an arbitrary index 'x'
```

e.g. (from your question):

```
$('#row_1 td').eq(3); // target the fourth <td>. Note index is 0-based
```

Comment: Thank you. The .eq(INDEX) option will work out great. That way I can get rid of the class="". Still trying to figure this jQuery stuff out.  Does the first option you gave loop through the entire table? I've seen on other examples jQuery has something for this, instead of doing the regular old loop.

Comment: @user1607759 Yes the first option loops through the rows in the table using the internal [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each) method. Depending on what you're doing though you can actually just chain methods on and they will apply to the entire collection of `<tr>` or `<td>` elements. You would need to be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the tds you can use something like this.

```
$("#row_1").find('td').each {function() {
  // do something
});
```

To get a specific td you can do this:

```
$('#row_1 .t1').something();
```